# JqGrid getCol() sum when custom format

Tags: jqgrid

I have a JqGrid whith a data footer where I'd like to put the sum of the column. I'd also like that that when the cell value equal zero in the grid, it will be color in grey. To do so I've creatted a custom formatter:

```
    currencyFmatter = function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    if (cellValue == 0)
        return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="color:#E1E1E1;">' +
            $.fn.fmatter('number', cellValue, options, rowObject)
          + '</span>';
    return $.fn.fmatter('number', cellValue, options, rowObject);
};
```

Which I call like this

```
{ name: 'Name', index: 'Name', align: 'center', width: '200px' },
                    { name: 'January', index: 'Months["January"].Amount', align: 'center', 
                      formatter:currencyFmatter}
```

The coloration is good but the sum in the data footer don't work anymore it always says 0.

```
loadComplete: function () {

                var janSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'January', false, 'sum');
                var febSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'February', false, 'sum');
                var marSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'March', false, 'sum');
                var aprSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'April', false, 'sum');
                var maySum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'May', false, 'sum');
                var junSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'June', false, 'sum');
                var julSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'July', false, 'sum');
                var augSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'August', false, 'sum');
                var sepSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'September', false, 'sum');
                var octSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'October', false, 'sum');
                var novSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'November', false, 'sum');
                var decSum = $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('getCol', 'December', false, 'sum');

                $('#jqgEndYear').jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Code: 'Total:',
                    January: janSum,
                    February: febSum,
                    March: marSum,
                    April: aprSum,
                    May: maySum,
                    June: junSum,
                    July: julSum,
                    August: augSum,
                    September: sepSum,
                    October: octSum,
                    November: novSum,
                    December: decSum
                });
            }
        });
```

If you have any idea of why the sum won't calculate, I be pleased to read it.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting) (unformatter) additionally to [formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to make the method [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) working with columns having custom formatter. See [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L3271) of [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L3251-3304) of `getCol` method.

Comment: @LotuX: `unformat` function should return the value which `getCol` can use in the `sum` operation. In your case I would recommend you to use `cellattr` instead of custom formatter.

Comment: @LotuX: The code could be something like the following `cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue) { return cellValue == 0 ? ' class="cellWithoutBackground" style="color:#E1E1E1;"' : ''; }`. You can use predefined formatter `'number'`.

Comment: Great Oleg, It's perfect I didn't know you can use cellatr. I works like a charm and the best is that I can use currency which is even better

Comment: @LotuX: You are welcome! The usage of `cellatr` is the best if you want set only some custom attributes like `style`, `class`, `title`, `onclick` and so on depend on contain of the cell or other cells in the row. Because it doesn't changed the cell contain you can use any formatter which you need. The feature come as extension of [this my old suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/custom-cell-tooltips-used-title-property-of-colmodel-as-the-function/#p21897).

Comment: And if I want to have this style also in the footerrow is there an easy way?

Comment: @LotuX: Do you mean to use the same formatter for the footer row like for the grid body? It defines the last parameter of `footerData`. If you mean `cellatr`, then it will be never used for the footer row.

Comment: Yeah I was meaning the cellatr, the goal is when the sum equal zero then it will be gray like the other cell in the grid.

Comment: @LotuX: You can insert HTML fragments in the data which you place in the footer with respect of `footerData`. It seem for me the only way.