# jqGrid sum a column in JS when column as null and "" values

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, sum

I found a nice way to sum a jqGrid column in javascript in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121350/jqgrid-access-cell-data-while-it-is-being-edited), like this:

```
var total = $('#grid_id').jqGrid('getCol','col_name',false,'sum');
```

This is great, but the problem I am having is that the column that I want to sum sometimes has white space instead of a number, and the variable `total` in the above example returns `NaN`.

Does anyone know how to tweak this function so that white space just acts like a zero?

Thanks!

** UPDATE **

as Oleg pointed out in the comments, you need to use a formatter in the colModel.  Once I put the `formatter: 'number'` in my colModel, all the whitespace is filled in as zeros and it works!  See thi example code:

```
$("#grid_id").jqGrid({
    url:'ajax_script.php?sql=' + sql1,
    height: 275,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    width: 800,
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:["Customer","Job", "Sched QNTY Sell","Sched Total Sell"],
    colModel:[
        {name:"Customer",index:"Customer",width:"16"},
        {name:"JobNum",index:"JobNum",width:"16"},
        {name:"Sched Qnty Sell",index:"Sched Qnty Sell",width:"20", formatter: 'number'},
        {name:"Sched Total Sell",index:"Sched Total Sell",width:"20", formatter: 'number'}
    ],
    rowNum:10000,
    sortname: 'Customer',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Scheduled to Bill',
    footerrow : true,
    altRows : true,
    gridComplete: function(){
        $(this).jqGrid('footerData','set',{'Customer':'TOTALS:'});
        var colnames = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
        for (var i = 2; i < colnames.length; i ++){
            var tot = $(this).jqGrid('getCol',colnames[i]['name'],false,'sum');
            var ob = [];
            ob[colnames[i]['name']] = tot;
            $(this).jqGrid('footerData','set',ob);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Which formatter you use for the column? Could you post more full definition of the grid which you use?

Comment: Oh Yes, the formatter, that is probably my problem as i am not using a formatter right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid first get the data from the cells of the column using either unformatter (if you define a formatter for the column) or just get `innerHTML` and decode the HTML (the characters "<" can be encoded in the form "<"). Then jqGrid use `parseFloat` to convert the data to the number. At the end the numbers will be sum up.

I think the bast way will be to trim the data before filling in the grid. If you can't do this on the server side you can use `beforeProcessing` callback.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to display those zeros on null columns a **unformat** option can be used:

```
{ name:"Column Name", index:"Column Index", width:"20", unformat: unformatNullColumn, formatter: 'number' }

function unformatNullColumn(cellvalue, options) {
    return (parseFloat(cellvalue) || 0);
}
```

It is explained very well in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9128370/612847).